# Use Envers in OSGi

Tags: hibernate, osgi, hibernate-envers

I have a somewhat working instance of Hibernate embedded into my OSGi context. Now I want to have Envers, too.

The [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch17.html#d5e5048) states:

> As of ORM 4.2, Envers is fully supported.

So it is possible. I'm just not sure how. I dutifully added `@Audited` to one of my entities, but nothing happened.

I tried to add these listeners to my *persistence.xml*:

```
 <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
 <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
 <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
 <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
 <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
 <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
```

It does not work because the listener classes don't exist anymore (I'm using Hibernate 5.1).

Other than that, there is no much documentation.

How do I enable Envers in OSGi?

*(PS. We are not going to use Eclipse Gemini or Apache Aries, because we evaluated them and they did not work for our use cases.)*

Comment: What OSGi Environment are you using?

Comment: The one in the current Eclipse platform. So... Equinox with a sprinkle of Felix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had this problem too.  Try these steps.

1. Listener no longer need to be set in the config file, follow the hibernate osgi instructions.
2. Make sure your hibernate bundles, especially hibernate-envers, starts before your entity bundles.
3. Make sure your persistence.xml file contains a valid entry such as

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>`

4. Look for Hibernate DDL errors, such as "Can't create primary key" that might interfer with registration
5. If referencing enums, see my answer here: [Classloader Issues with Envers in OSGi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933175/classloader-issues-with-envers-in-osgi)
6. Put a breakpoint in EnversIntegrator.integrate to see make sure it is called on not bailing out.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but throwing this here in case anyone else needs it:

Steven's first two points are spot on.  Hibernate bootstrapping looks fairly different in OSGi than it does in SE/EE land.  We have numerous tickets in JIRA tracking enhancements, especially to make things more dynamic and to reduce the brittleness of startup ordering (Steven is absolutely correct that hibernate-core, hibernate-envers, etc. **must** currently be started first prior to your bundle).

Our hibernate-demos project has a few OSGi quickstarts, all of which include Envers setup.  This one is probably more of what you're looking for: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-demos/tree/master/hibernate-orm/osgi/unmanaged-native

Comment: It's hard for me to translate the example to my setup. Could you link me the file that has the start positions? And maybe whatever else is relevant to start the bundles in plain OSGi?