# Classloader Issues with Envers in OSGi

Tags: osgi, hibernate-envers

I've successfully started Hibernate in an OSGi context, and now I want to add Envers.

[The documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_optional_modules) claims that's possible. I don't believe it anymore. There is no documentation of any kind for this subject and nobody seems to have actually done it. Moreover even with a Blueprint implementation I had to hack the classloader to make Hibernate even find Envers:

```
osgiClassLoader = new org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiClassLoader();
osgiClassLoader.addBundle(requestingBundle);
osgiClassLoader.addBundle(FrameworkUtil.getBundle(SessionFactory.class));
osgiClassLoader.addBundle(FrameworkUtil.getBundle(HibernateEntityManagerFactory.class));
osgiClassLoader.addBundle(FrameworkUtil.getBundle(EnversService.class));

Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(osgiClassLoader);
```

*(I feel like I should be asking: "Is Envers in OSGi even possible?" So if you have a definite answer for that question, please let me know. I've been spending way too much time on these issues.)*

However the actual problem has nothing to do with Hibernate / Envers and all with OSGi. Both want to access the entities and enums used. With reflection nonetheless. Of course they can't. And of course I can't add Import-Packages.

The relevant stack trace looks something like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.acme.project.MyEnum cannot be found by org.hibernate.core_5.1.0.Final
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.setParameterValues(EnumType.java:105)
    ... 62 more
```

Normally with OSGi-agnostic frameworks I'd just add something like this to the *MANIFEST.MF*:

```
// to org.hibernate.core
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered
// to org.acme.project
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: org.hibernate.core
```

However I can't add anything to Hibernate's manifest. I tried contributing the line via fragment, but that did not work either.

I even tried adding the entire Hibernate dependencies as JAR into a plug-in to add the above. It won't work.

How to resolve these classloader issues?

Comment: have you tried exporting the package org.acme.project ?

Comment: @isco It is exported. But `org.hibernate.core` can't import it.

Comment: hmm, your hibernate modules, are they deployed as bundles or embeded ? same question for the module containing MyEnum ?

Comment: @isco The module containing MyEnum is a regular old bundle. For Hibernate I tried both.

Comment: According to the spec (osgi §3.14) it should be possible to add the required import definitions to org.hibernate.core with a fragment bundle. Never actually tried that myself though.

Comment: @user3653004 I tried that already. And of course it works. It's just not practical.

Comment: in the deployed version, I don't see why it wouldn't work, is the bundle hibernate-osgi installed ?

Comment: @isco Yes, it has to be to throw exceptions. Maybe I misunderstood? What do you mean by deployed / embedded?

Comment: No you are right, my bad

Comment: If you take a look at the `hibernate-orm` project on github.com, you'll see a hibernate-osgi project with a test `OsgiIntgrationTest` that exposes both ORM and Envers together.  Does this example not work for you?

Comment: @Naros I would assume this example works. But it has a dependency to every library Apache ever made, which are really hard to get since our application resides in an Eclipse RCP / Equinox environment. I'd have to spent hours getting the dependencies and then hours trying to figure out how to remove all these unnecessary dependencies again.

Comment: Understood.  FWIW, Hibernate 6 has Envers embedded, so this OSGi problem should disappear for good.  I know that doesn't help now, but hopefully its a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your @Audited class references an Enum, org.hibernate.core needs to import the classes package.  The best way to do this is to register a fragment bundle.

Also, it is wise to make sure your start level for hibernate bundles is lower than the start levels for entity bundles.

Here is a snippet from a sample Gradle script to create a fragment bundle.  Make sure your change the org.hibernate.core bundle version to the one you are using, and also update the 'your.package' to the one that contains your Enum.

```
/*
When using Envers, entities that reference Enum classes must be imported (Import-Package) by the org.hibernate.core bundle.
 */

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'biz.aQute.bnd:biz.aQute.bnd.gradle:3.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'biz.aQute.bnd.builder'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Fragment-Host': 'org.hibernate.core;' + 'bundle-version=' + '5.2.9.Final',
                'Import-Package': 'your.package'
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, bundle fragments should be avoided like the plague, and in this case it's actually unnecessary.  You were absolutely correct about startup ordering.  But a step further: if Hibernate ORM uses proper OSGi bootstrapping (I'll throw details in a separate answer), we already have full visibility into the client/persistence bundle (we add the bundle's classloader to the aggregate classloader we use throughout Hibernate itself).  If that bootstrapping is skipped, you'll start to see these types of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but throwing this here in case anyone else needs it:

Hibernate bootstrapping looks fairly different in OSGi than it does in SE/EE land.  We have numerous tickets in JIRA tracking enhancements, especially to make things more dynamic and to reduce the brittleness of startup ordering (Steven is absolutely correct that hibernate-core, hibernate-envers, etc. **must** currently be started first prior to your bundle).

I'd highly advise against the bundle fragment approaches, but I'll comment why on Steven's answer.

Our hibernate-demos project has a few OSGi quickstarts, all of which include Envers setup.  This one is probably more of what you're looking for: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-demos/tree/master/hibernate-orm/osgi/unmanaged-native

Comment: So what specifically creates the 'bootstrapping' that imports the Enum per my example?  Is it one of the manual imports in the POM?  I'm trying to trace why I needed to use the fragment in the first place.

Comment: Have a look at that project for an example (or https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/osgi/OSGi.html).  The magic happens when you get a SessionFactory instance by using the OSGi service registry.  Internally, our service gets access to the "requesting bundle" and adds that context to our classloading concepts, giving us full access to all classes in the client bundle.

Fragments do something a little similar, but have a lot of unfortunate sideeffects.  Plus, it side-steps a lot of other important bootstrapping on our side.  Using the service registry is key!

Comment: "The magic happens when you get a SessionFactory instance by using the OSGi service registry. Internally, our service gets access to the "requesting bundle" and adds that context to our classloading concepts" - That's what we are doing.  Everything works (other classes get loaded), just not Enums.  That's why we had to workaround the problem with the fragment.

Comment: @StevenSpungin, if that's the case, hit me with a ticket on our JIRA?  https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa